# Ionic hybrid mobile app get device location

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

We are developing a mobile app with Ionic/Cordova and Angular 5. We have to display a distance either in metric or imperial system depending on the locale of the device settings. At that point of the app we already have a value in meters which we have to transform accordingly.

We don't want to do another network call so the locale must be extracted from the device.

Is there a build-in way with our tech stack to do this or is there a plugin for extracting device settings?

We use:

- Ionic 3
- Angular 5
- Typescript 2.4
- cordova-android 6.3
- cordova-ios 4.5.4

I found this https://angular.io/guide/i18n guide and we would prefer to use the `LOCALE_ID` but this is not a must.

Comment: Clarification: All we want to know is if the user has its phone set to US locale or not, so we can decide to show him Imperial or Metric units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found a solution which works on mobile devices without doing another Network call. The first line reads the locale from the device settings, the second line extracts the country of the locale.

Unfortunately, this is not reliable in browsers but good enough for our mobile only use case.

```
const locale = window.navigator.language;
const country = locale.split('-')[1];
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this. It gives something like this 'en-US'
For me, my language is en-US but my country is India.
(This way it failed)
Let me know if any other workaround.

Comment: Same with me. I am also looking for a solution, but could not find anything that would work reliably.

Answer (score 1):

Use the new `navigator` object (you are creating an hybrid app, I assume you're up-do-date with the versions of your browsers)

```
let lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; // Language
let showPosition = (position) => {
  position.coords.latitude;
  position.coords.longitude; 
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); // Geoposition
```

Comment: we don't want to do another network call, we need the local device settings

Comment: Sorry, what ? This is the exact answer you gave and marked as resolved, there's absolutely no network call here. I don't appreciate this kind of behavior ...

Comment: Your answer seems to be totally valid but is too specific for our use case. We don't need a position, all we need is the country of the device settings. pls see my clarification and thx for your effort

Comment: You clarification is **my answer**. This is the first line of the code I provided. I gave you Geoposition because you could base your unit system on location rather than language preference (for instance, in America, you display imperial units). You're actually saying I give you too much answers, so it's not what you asked ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        //this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        //this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      });
    }
```